# Как получить значение атрибута href из localStorage и поместить его в link с файлом сss?

Tags: javascript, html, css, localstorage

Сделал что-то вроде темного режима по клику на кнопку. Тут принцип таков: есть 2 css-файла. 1 - light.css, 2 - dark.css (светлая и темная темы соответственно. Смена режимов работает при изменении значения атрибута href на теге link c ссылкой на css-файл. По нажатию на кнопку тему тема меняется, как и соответствующее значение в localStorage. Но совсем не выходит получать это значение из localStorage и записывать его в значение атрибута href сразу же после обновления страницы автоматически. В общем, пытаюсь сохранять выбранную тему после обновления страницы. Ниже указан код:

```
function ChangeTheme() {
    let lightTheme = 'css/light.css';
    let darkTheme = 'css/dark.css';
    var theme = '';

    var currentTheme = link.getAttribute('href');

    if (currentTheme == darkTheme) {
        currentTheme = lightTheme;
        theme = 'css/light.css';
    } else {
        currentTheme = darkTheme;
        theme = 'css/dark.css';
    }
    localStorage.setItem('href', theme);
    link.setAttribute('href', localStorage.getItem('href'));
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, откуда взялся link? Он объявлен выше? Где именно подключаются стили и скрипт? Уточните пожалуйста вопрос

Comment: var btn = document.querySelector('#theme-button');
var link = document.querySelector('#theme-link');
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href id="theme-link">

Всё,объявлено, всё работает. И скрипты и стили, в html файле. Ты можешь просто помочь?
При отправке вопросы эту часть не пропускало.

Answer (score 0):

Может не стоит изобретать очередной велосипед ? Вот [рабочий вариант](https://webdevtips.pro/js/dark-theme/).
Если хорошо покопаться, то можно найти ещё проще метод по запросу `как включить темную тему js` Там вообще без JS на переключениях переменных в СSS/ Если вам поддерживать только новые браузеры.